# Kafka - How to guarantee the messages from different topics are arriving in order

Tags: apache-kafka

I am new in Kafka topic and have a question:
Assume that I am building the banking app and the broker server has two topics: one for the deposit and one for the withdraw. Each time the customer performs the action, messages will be sent to the corresponding topic. Logically the deposit messages should be arrived before the withdraw messages otherwise an exception will be thrown here, but it's not always the case, i.e: bad network connection...

In this case how can I make sure that the arriving messages will be in the same order as the sending messages, although they are sent in two different topics?

Comment: You could create a consumer from one topic on retrieval of data from another topic

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Message ordering is only guaranteed within a partition of a given topic.